# File Size and Format before uploading

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to check for file format and size of the file before uploading it in javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You can check for the extension but still it could be wrong *because a text file renamed to zip will show you zip as an extension*. You need [server-side script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) for that.

Once file is **uploaded**, you can check its **[mime-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)** and **size** with server-side script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've obtained the `fileTobeUploaded` object (i don't know how you are doing the upload), with the following you could get the size in bytes.

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    alert(theFile.size);
})(fileTobeUploaded);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can retrieve size information about the file using FLASH, however to determine the file format, you will most probably need to rely on the file extension... and that's a weak determination with regards to security (malware etc.)